# Computing intersection of two subspaces of $C^{\infty}_{2\pi}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've been thinking of the following two subspaces of $C^{\infty}_{2\pi}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$:
$$
A=\{a_1\sin(t)+a_2\sin(2t)+a_3\sin(3t):a_1,a_2,a_3\in\mathbb{R}\}
$$
and
$$
B=\{b_1\sin(t)+b_2\sin^2(t)+b_3\sin^3(t):b_1,b_2,b_3\in\mathbb{R}\}.
$$
I'm wondering if there's an explicit description of $A\cap B$?

Using double and triple angle identities, I deduce
$$
a_1\sin(t)+a_2\sin(2t)+a_3\sin(3t)=(a_1+2a_2\cos(t)+3a_3)\sin(t)-4a_3\sin^3(t).
$$
The Wronskian of $\{\sin(t),\sin^2(t),\sin^3(t)\}$ is $2\sin^3(t)\cos^3(t)$, so they are linearly independent on $\mathbb{R}$. This leads me to suspect that $A\cap B=\langle \sin(t),\sin^3(t)\rangle$, but the pesky $\cos(t)$ in the coefficient of $\sin(t)$ above is bugging me. Is my hunch correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deduction shows that $\sin(t)$ and $\sin^3(t)=\frac34\sin(t)-\frac14\sin(3t)$ are elements of $A\cap B$, so the dimension of $A\cap B$ is at least $2$. Thus either in fact $$A\cap B=\{a_1\sin(t)+a_3\in(3t):a_1,a_3\in\mathbb R\}$$ or $A=B$. But $A=B$ cannot hold as $B$ contains the even function $\sin^2(t)$, whereas all nonzero elements of $A$ are odd functions. (Alternatively for the last step: $\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$ for all $f\in A$, but $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(x)\,\mathrm dx=\pi$)

Comment: Thanks! What does the notation $a_1\sin(t)+a_3\in (3t)$ mean here?